# xcode library not found for -lAFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have a ObjC app project with a UI Automation Swift target in it. By default the Run and Test build work successfully.

But I have to add a Cocoa Pod with a Swift framework for the UI Automation target... Podfile:

```
workspace 'BlahApp.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '8.0'
project 'BlahApp/BlahApp.xcodeproj'

target 'BlahApp' do
    pod 'Blahpod', '~> 2.1.6'
    pod 'Mehpod', '~> 3.10.0'
end

target 'BlahAppUITests' do
    use_frameworks!
    platform :ios, '9.0'
    pod 'autom', :git => 'https://blah.to.my.repo', :branch => 'master'
end
```

So I add this, do a `pod install`, Xcode clean, Xcode **Run** --> works, Xcode **Test** fails with:

> ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking

`AFNetworking` is used in Blahpod.

Time wasted trying to get Xcode/Cocoapods to do what I want: 2 days

Somebody please help me here. tried other people's solution to the error message to no avail.

Comment: Check my comment at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152965/library-not-loaded-alamofire/45180199#45180199

Comment: Hi @Joe! This is what's in my Runpath and framework search path: `$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks @loader_path/Frameworks` / `$(inherited) "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/AFNetworking-framework" "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/autom"` ... not working!

Comment: Oddly enough, it works on some of my targets, on others not. I will just duplicate a target on that it works and go with that for now.

Answer (score -1):

**in build setting , search for Run Path
then add "@executable_path/Frameworks" and Remove All other Content Related to AFNetworking**